# Order of execution Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
setTimeout(function timeout() {
    console.log('timeout');
}, 0);

let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('create promise');
    resolve();
});

p.then(function(){
    console.log('execute promise');
});

console.log('end');
```

I get this order when execute the code:

- create promise
- end
- execute promise
- timeout

Question: Why `create promise` is executed first?  I expect to execute first `end`, because it is the only one synchrone code so it should be first executed.

Comment: the promise function is called immediately in most implementations. there's no need to defer its execution

Comment: @DanielA.White, then do i understand correct that all that is inside `new Promise(...)` is executed synchronously?

Comment: yes - the standard says so: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise-constructor

Answer (score 1):

The callback passed to the `Promise` constructor is executed immediately and **synchronously**. But it is possible to start an **asynchronous** task in a `Promise` callback. Then the `Promise` resolves after the **asynchronous** task has completed. This is the primary use-case of `Promises`.

In your case there is no **asynchronous** task started, so all your cody is **synchronous**.